# Delete partition option is disabled, why?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I've deleted my F drive in order to extend volume of C.
Now I've to delete this free space. But the delete partition option is disabled. Why? What should I do now?

[image: Disabled delete partition]

Comment: Your screenshot shows the context menu of free space, which is not a partition, so it can't be deleted. Are partition context menus disabled as well? Please [edit] your question and update the screenshot.

Comment: You delete something and get free space. What do you expect to get by deleting *free space*?

Comment: I want to make it unallocated space in order to extend volume of C drive.
Now Extend volume option in C drive is disabled!

Comment: To extend `C:` you need to shrink the extended partition (dark green box). I think in your case this is technically possible without moving filesystems, a good tool should be able to do this in place (I cannot recommend one though, not my scope). Then you will have this free space *outside* of the extended partition, adjacent to `C:`, which will make extending `C:` possible.

Comment: The green boarder  has been the unallocated space. Besides, the green boarder free space is next to drive C. You can right click on the drive C . You may see the function of expand the drive in the right click menu.

Comment: The option 'Extend Volume' for C is disabled deleting the next drive!

Comment: In order for you to be able to extend C with the on board tool from Windows you'd need to delete "My Desktop", "Educational", "Media" and finally the extended partition itself. Only after doing that you'd have the space to extend your C drive as it is a primary partition that isn't part of the extended partition. As it is the extended partition is "blocking the way" for the C partition to extend.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your screenshot your will notice a green boarder around some of the partitions that's also enclosing the "old" partition. This is what's called an extended partition. It's likely a disk that uses the MBR format instead of GPT.

As such you're only supposed to have 4 partitions on it. The workaround to have more is to have one of the four primary partitions be an extended partition which can contain logical partitions.

Essentially you already freed up space within the extended partition.

You currently have three primary petitions (System, C: and the extended partition) and within your extended partition you have 3 more logical partitions and 207 GB of free space which you could use to setup another logical partition. To create a fourth primary partition you would need to rearrange your partition layout which can not be done with the windows tool (easily) as it would require you to shrink the extended partition to have those 207 GB be outside of it either at the front or back.

You will need to user other tools to do this kind of reallocation (there are quite a few of them). Make sure to backup your data before as it is considered a "dangerous" operation as you need to redefine the borders of partitions and/or move the data.